# How to merge two python dictionaries with elements on the same level?

Tags: python, dictionary

In the following usable example code I define two dictionaries `a` and `b` which I want to combine

```
a = {'device': {'version': '1.2.3'}}
b = {'device': {'name': 'testdevice'}}
c = {'other':  {'cost': '1000'}}

q = {}
q.update(a)
q.update(b)
q.update(c)
print q

p = {}
p = dict(p.items() + a.items())
p = dict(p.items() + b.items())
p = dict(p.items() + c.items())
print p
```

i.e. the resulting dictionary should be equal to

```
result = {'device': {'name': 'testdevice', 'version': '1.2.3'}, 'other': {'cost':'1000'}}
```

but the two examples in the code always give:

```
{'device': {'name': 'testdevice'}, 'other': {'cost':'1000'}}
```

Is there a simple way (without classes/functions) to achieve this?

I want to combine the dictionary entries of the same level. It can be assumed there are only two levels. The example code itself can be simplified, but it will be used later in a loop where many dictionaries might be 'added/merged' together.

Comment: Your use of `update` is not correct, and the existing answers demonstrate the right way to use it. When you write `q.update(b)` *after* updating `q` with `a`, that is a mistake. You don't want to further update `q` itself, rather you want to update some of the dictionaries that reside at key locations *within* `q`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:

```
>>> a = {'device': {'version': '1.2.3'}}
>>> b = {'device': {'name': 'testdevice'}}
>>> c = {'other':  {'cost': '1000'}}
>>> to_merge = [a,b,c]
>>> d = {}
>>> for m in to_merge:
...     for k,v in m.items():
...         d.setdefault(k, {}).update(v)
...         
>>> d
{'device': {'version': '1.2.3', 'name': 'testdevice'}, 'other': {'cost': '1000'}}
```

Although I don't know why you're opposed to using functions.  Wouldn't it make sense to wrap this up in a `merge_list_of_dictionaries` function?

Comment: setdefault is really the key to value... Thanks.

Comment: @Alex: no, the proper use of `update` is really at the heart of your question. This is a more verbose way to do what can be done more simply with `update` calls at the appropriate level within your dictionaries. Don't get me wrong, this answer is a good one, but @Alexander Zhukov's answer is the one that addresses the conceptual mistake that was preventing your code from working in the post. It's unfortunate that you are dismissing that very helpful answer.

Comment: I just wanted to note this, so that others who read the question don't mistakenly think that using `setdefault` is the parsimonious solution, especially for a problem so easily handled with rudimentary use of `update`.

Comment: @Alex: `setdefault` is simply a shortcut so that you don't have to branch on `if k in d` or use a `defaultdict` to get an automatic `{}`.  There's nothing special about it.

Answer (score 2):

There is an `update` method, which, I guess, is what you're looking for:

```
    a['device'].update(b['device'])
```

Comment: No I am not. I know there is an update method (see example), but it does not work as I expect to. Remember: the dict might have ANY value, I just want to merge the ones on the same level

Comment: You are looking for `update` and the available answers address your problem. See my comment on the OP.